Are group convolutions still used?
Group convolutions theoretically should reduce the number of parameters and hence improve the speed of inference, without significantly affecting the performance of the model. However, I don't notice them used extensively in CNN architectures / CNN components of larger architectures. Also, when I tried to change groups parameter in convolutional layers in Tensorflow I noticed worse inference speed, which is counterintuitive. I'm wondering if they are still used in practice.
